# Number Base conversion and digits access?

Tags: c++, types, radix

The language is c++

I have to read in some data from 0 - n, n could theoretically be infinity. Based on the value of n, I have to change the numbers over from decimal to that base, even if its base 10000. So if I read in 5 numbers, n=5, I have to convert them over to base5.

That said, I am not sure how to do the conversion, but I'm sure I could get it reading over some article. But what really concerns me is when I convert over to whatever the n base might be what type would my result be to store in an array? Long?

Once I get the converted numbers in some array, how would I access each individual digit in each number for manipulation later?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you convert a decimal integer into binary, octal, hexadecimal? If yes, just observe the pattern among them, find out the relations, understand the rules; once you understand it you would be able to generalize this. If no, then first learn that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion from decimal to base is done by division / modulo. x is the decimal number, b is the target base.

1. r = x % b
2. y = (x-r) : b
3. replace x by y and repeat from 1 until y becomes 0
4. the result are the r's, bottom up

Beneath of that you'll have to create a `std::map` with replacement patterns for the numbers in r, i. e. for base 16 some entries would be `10 -> A, 11 -> B`. This implies, that you'll have to think about a representation form for very large `n`.

BTW: Consider a book about programming 101, conversion of decimal to bin / oct / hex is **always** explainend and easily adaptable for other bases.

Comment: Its been a while since I've had to think about conversions, yes I was being lazy by asking that. Somewhere I have an assembly book with that in it I'm sure. I wasn't too concerned about that, more about the array storage of the conversions and accessing the individual digits. I don't have to map.

Comment: `map` is just a hint for replacement. So if you just have to print the result, using `map` is easier implemented than a large `case` or `if-then-else`-chain. You could read the input for `map` from a file or hard-code it.

Comment: I can get it to convert, that works, but here is my confusion: lets say I convert 20 to base2, that is 10100, that's great but how do I now assemble this into a complete number?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish the above. If I have a data[] array and slot 1 has the number 20 to convert to base 2 as above, how do I put the result back into slot 1? so data[1] = 10100 as a complete number, not individual ints? Make sense?

Comment: Just create a second array, better a `std::vector`, save the decoded values there. You just have to ensure, that each number is in the correct position. So you would have `indata[1] = 20` and `outdata[1] = "10100"`(saved as string). Now, this makes sense to you?

Comment: It does, but I can't do it. I need to keep as an int. I thought there was a way to "shift" it back to a complete number or something. It makes me think I'm going about this all wrong. I was going to do something similar and keep in a linked list, but still that seems like overkill.

Comment: If you need to keep this as an int, then use another `map`, the key is your int with the original representation and the value is a string for output representation. So whenever you need to output a number in the given base you access the map and it returns the output string.

Comment: Thanks, I used an array of linked list objects. I would think I could have compacted the number back to a single var? I saw some article where people turned the digits to strings, concatenated and then turned back into a number, cheap to me. The guy I'm working with is a CE, I would think he would know right away.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, most manipulations you're going to perform on a number are base-invariant. This means that you can add/sub/mul/div (And even perform power/root/log operations) two numbers without even knowing their base.
Think about it this way, the computer does nothing special when it adds two unsigned ints even thou all it's really working with is a 32 digits base-2 number.

You can probably make due with using ints (or whatever data type you need) and convert the base during display.

Comment: Thanks, I have not done low level stuff in so long, this helps.